# Use of spi_setcfg() API for configuration of spi using qnx

Tags: spi, qnx

I am new to QNX. I am trying to write an application which sends/receives data over SPI. I am able to send/receive data. But when I observe clock line with MOSI line on logic analyser, I see that after every 32 bytes there is a gap of 5 us for which both clock and MOSI lines fall flat and no data is transferred during that period. Now due to this, the time taken for transfer of spi data is coming to be more than calculated time. 
I am assuming ( I am not sure if it's correct) that Qnx spi fifo buffer size is 32 bytes , so Qnx spi driver pushes the data in chunks of 32 bytes. That is the reason why there is delay of 5 ms to fill data again into buffers. I want to know if there is any way by which we can increase spi fifo buffer size. I did some research and got to understand that spi_setcfg() API can be used to change configure SPI. But I could not find any examples of how to use this API to increase fifo buffer. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I use:

```
uint32_t spiMode      = ( ( BITS_PER_BYTE & SPI_MODE_CHAR_LEN_MASK ) |
                                 SPI_MODE_IDLE_INSERT | SPI_MODE_BODER_MSB |
                                 SPI_MODE_RDY_EDGE |
                                 SPI_MODE_CSHOLD_HIGH );
```